# Qt5 error: ‘ColorKeyMap’ does not name a type

Tags: qt, qt5, qcolor

I am writing a class which has the following structure:

Header File:

```
#pragma once

#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtWidgets>

class VirtualButton : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        VirtualButton( QWidget *parent );

    private:
        static QMap<unsigned int, QColor> ColorKeyMap;
        static QList<unsigned int> goodKeys;
};
```

CppFile

```
#include "VirtualButton.hpp"

QMap<unsigned int, QColor> VirtualButton::ColorKeyMap = QMap<unsigned int, QColor>();
ColorKeyMap[ 23 ] = QColor( 0xff, 0x00, 0xff );

QList<unsigned int> VirtualButton::goodKeys = QList<unsigned int>() << 50 << 62 << 37 << 133 << 64 << 108 << 135 << 109;

VirtualButton::VirtualButton( QWidget *parent ) : QWidget( parent ) {

    setFixedSize( 48, 48 );
};

int main( int argv, char **argv ) {

    QApplication app( argc, argv );

    VirtualButton *btn = new VirtualButton();
    btn->show();

    return app.exec()
}
```

When I compile this code I get the following error:

```
VirtualKeyboard.cpp:4:1: error: ‘ColorKeyMap’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘QColormap’?
 ColorKeyMap[ 23 ] = QColor( 0xff, 0x00, 0xff );
 ^~~~~~~~~~~
 QColormap
```

Why does this error come up? I can see that goodKeys has no issue, but ColorKeyMap does. Is this because QColor should not be used outside the class?

Comment: change to `VirtualButton::ColorKeyMap[ 23 ] = QColor( 0xff, 0x00, 0xff );`

Comment: I've tried even that. Does not work. Joey's expansion is nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of mistakes in your code.

1. The main problem is that you want to modify for a certain *key, namely `23` the value of color, namely `QColor( 0xff, 0x00, 0xff );`

   The problem is although you can initialize a private static member outside of your class like you did, you cannot modify it later. You cannot even read it later outside the class. You can only access it in the future through a member function of the class `VirtualButton`.

Fortunately, there is work around. You can use a static function (namely `initColorKeyMap()`) to initialize your static member `ColorKeyMap`, as shown in the code below.

## virtualbutton.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QtWidgets/QtWidgets>
#include <QMap>
#include <QList>

class VirtualButton : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    VirtualButton( QWidget *parent );

private:
    static QMap<unsigned int, QColor> initColorKeyMap();
    static QMap<unsigned int, QColor> ColorKeyMap;
    static QList<unsigned int> goodKeys;
};
```

## virtualbutton.cpp

```
#include "virtualbutton.h"

QMap<unsigned int, QColor> VirtualButton::initColorKeyMap() {
    QMap<unsigned int, QColor> temp = QMap<unsigned int, QColor>();
    temp[ 23 ] = QColor( 0xff, 0x00, 0xff );
    return temp;
}
QMap<unsigned int, QColor> VirtualButton::ColorKeyMap = VirtualButton::initColorKeyMap();

QList<unsigned int> VirtualButton::goodKeys = QList<unsigned int>() << 50 << 62 << 37 << 133 << 64 << 108 << 135 << 109;

VirtualButton::VirtualButton( QWidget *parent ) : QWidget( parent ) {
    setFixedSize( 48, 48 );
}
```

- There were a couple of mistakes/mistmatches in your `main()` also, but I guess they were just smaller side problems and not your main concern. Anyways, here is the main.cpp also with minor corrections and some additional code. *(With added coded, I wanted to test your Button class, until I realized that it has not been derived from QPushButton and so I can't show a VirtualButton on the widget. Just realized it later. Anyways, it had no bearing on the real problem at hand. The code compiles with a correctly initialized `ColorKeyMap`)*

## main.cpp

```
#include "virtualbutton.h"
#include <QtCore>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QWidget window;
    window.resize(320, 240);
    window.setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("childwidget", "Child widget"));
    window.show();

//    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(
//        QApplication::translate("childwidget", "Press me"), &window);

    VirtualButton *button = new VirtualButton(&window);
    // button->move(100, 100);
    button->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Other than that the code compiles without a problem.

Comment: Firstly, yes it is to be accessed only by members of the class. Secondly, even when I made the variables public, I believe I got the same error. I'll check and get back to you. In the mean time, I have done the same thing. I used a static function initStaticVars() and did the job.

Comment: In reply to your comment, I had to post this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886548/variables-can-only-be-declared-globally-but-cannot-be-modified-initialized-s/54887181#54887181).

Comment: Thank you for the link. That is very informative. I can understand the language a bit better.. :)

Comment: Anyways, I was writing [QVKbd](https://github.com/marcusbritanicus/QVKbd/), an on-screen keyboard for X11 based on Qt. You can see the implementation there. I can see that it isn't necessary for me to use a `mInitDone` flag at all. Thanks.