# Variables can only be "declared" globally, but cannot be modified/(initialized separately)

Tags: c++, c, global-variables

**Disclaimer:**

- This might be a very trivial question *(although I cannot find an answer for it)*, and
- a purely theoretical question *(I never needed to do this, nor ever saw code that uses such constructs, but I am just curious how/why this happens the way it does.)*
- The `C/C++` double tag, because I tested the bit of code on both C and C++ and it is just 4 lines of code *(and the only difference is that `gcc/clang` give a warning while `g++/clang++` give an error.)*

**Background:**
In replying to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54864947/qt5-error-colorkeymap-does-not-name-a-type/54867539#54867539), I started to think about why the OP can not **modify** a `public static` variable. I thought about it a bit and then reduced the problem a bit further, where I can see the same effect, but without needing any class or static member variables.

**Question**: Then the following code can reproduce the observation.

```
int global_n; // I know it can be initialized right away here also: int global_n = 1;
global_n = 2; // This does not compile in C++. In C it gives a warning about missing type-specifier

int main() {
    global_n = 2; // This does compile in both C/C++ of course
}
```

1. Which brings me to my question: Global variables (and hence `static` variables/member-variables) can only be initialized, directly there when they are declared. But any subsequent modifications can only occur inside a function. Correct?
2. Any specific reason for this?

Comment: Interesting, what about this? `int a = 1; int b = (a = 2, 3);` It seems to modify `a` outside of a function but is it legal? I have no idea. Or this `int a = 1; int b = (++a, 3);`

Comment: No, it is because `global_n = 2;` is in the wrong scope in C. It must be within a function, not because it cannot be modified.

Comment: You mix run-time and compile-time. The second example is run-time; the first example is illegal and should be `int global_n= 2;`, which is compile time.

Comment: And same for C++, needs to be in a scope, or should be passed in during construction.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, that is all one code. Not two examples. Hmm, interesting "compile-time versus run-time difference", I hadn't thought about it from that angle.

Comment: @john, I tested. `:)` Both your examples are legal.

Comment: @JoeyMallone, they are both illegal: `initializer is not a constant`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I am assuming C++, I should have made that clear.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, the `g++/clang++` compilers say that those examples from john are valid code. I just tested with `gcc/clang` now and they don't compile with the error you mentioned your comment.

Comment: OK. Valid C++, but invalid C.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, No, my apologies for double tagging then. I am bit surprised here. Just 4 lines of code can have differences for C and C++. I didn't think that through before.

Comment: Even 1 single line can be different for C and C++.

Comment: @Gerhardh, I understand that now. Just that the example was so trivial, I couldn't have imagined, it having an effect. It's a good example for how different the languages are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outside of a function, you cannot have statements (i.e. executable lines of code), only declarations and definitions.

In the case of `global_n = 2;` at global scope, C90 has a legacy feature that if a variable is declared without a type then the has a default type of `int` (C99 removed the feature and requires a type).  That's what's happening in this case, and that's also why you get a warning about the type missing.

C++ doesn't have that rule, so this appears as a statement outside of a function which is an error.

Comment: So what's wrong with the examples I posted? Expressions can modify global variables.

Comment: @john Not *modify*, but *initialize*, and only **constant expressions** i.e. those that can be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: C++ can have non-constant expressions (e.g. function calls) as initializers, even of global variables. C cannot.

Comment: C++ doesn't require constant initializers (this is why answering dual tagged posts is such a pickle)

Comment: @dbush I think you are thinking of C, even though your answer explicitly mentions C++.

Comment: @StoryTeller, I am sorry. It was just 4 lines of code. I thought (the double tagging) wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @JoeyMallone - Oh, double tagging doesn't have to be inherently wrong. But I think that imposes a different standard on answers (given the fact two different language standard need to be considered).

Comment: `Outside of a function, you cannot have statements` Well, you can have declaration statements :) I don't know if there's a difference in terminology in C, though.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that the syntax doesn't allow to execute code outside of compound statements `{...}`, end of story.

But if digging a bit deeper, C also does not allow things like

```
// file scope
int x = 0;
int y = x;
```

Nor does C allow this:

```
// file scope
int x = func();
```

The reason for this is that file scope variables, and variables declared as `static` all have *static storage duration*. Such variables are actually not initialized on the line where you declarate them, but much earlier on, before main() is even called. (This goes for C++ objects with static storage duration too.)

There is always start-up code executed before main() is called, even if you don't see it. This is often called "C runtime" or "CRT". Part of it's job is to initialize all variables/objects with static storage duration before main() is called.

So if you have this application code:

```
void foo (void)
{
  static int var = 1;
  printf("%d", var);
}

int main (void)
{
  foo();
}
```

Then the code executed before `main` will look something like this simplified pseudo code:

```
void startup (void) // point of entry when executable starts
{
  set memory of "var" to 1
  main();
}
```

This is actually the reason why we can call `foo` multiple times without re-initializing `var`. The line `static int var = 1;` isn't actually executed where it is placed in the source, but much earlier on, and only once. Unlike local variables, that are often initialized at the same place in the code as the declaration.

The "CRT" initialization is roughly split in three parts:

- `.data` initialization which sets all static storage duration variables that are explicitly initialized to a value by the programmer, like `var` in my example.
- `.bss` initialization which sets all variables to zero, that are either initialized to zero by the programmer, or not initialized at all.
- Initialization of C++ objects with static storage duration, by their respective initializers.

Apart from such C++ constructs, no application code is called at start-up, which is why code like `int x = func();` isn't allowed in C.

This is also the reason why C++ objects with static storage duration shouldn't be made to rely on each other's initialization values: the order of declaration in the source doesn't necessarily correspond with the order of initialization in the "CRT".

Comment: Before the mandatory pedantic comments: this post is intentionally simplified for the sake of reaching out beginners. Yes, there are exceptions and there's a lot more going on behind the lines, and yes C and C++ are slightly different in many ways here, but we can leave that discussion for another post.

Comment: C++ allows function calls in file scope initializers.  `int x = func();` compiles.

Comment: @dbush Yeah, yeah. See the comment above.

Comment: Fine, fixed. You can all move on with your lives now.

Comment: @Lundin, thanks for detailed explanation. I don't have a background in "Computer Science", so always good to know the stuff going on behind the scene.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is regarding C++. C may be different.

> Global variables (and hence static variables/member-variables) can only be initialized, directly there when they are declared.

True, it is only possible to provide an initialiser in a declaration. It is however possible to provide declarations without an initialiser. Example:

```
extern int global_n; // only declaration; no definition; no initialiser
int global_n = 42;   // re-declaration; definition; initialiser
```

> But any subsequent modifications can only occur inside a function. Correct?

Not strictly true. It is possible to modify global variables in an initialiser of another global variable:

```
int global_n1 = 666;
int global_n2 = global_n1 = 42;
```

This is probably a bad design choice in practice - at least in this simplified example; I suppose there can be practical use case out there.

> Any specific reason for this?

I presume you mean, any specific reason why you can only have declaration statements, and no other kind of statement outside of functions?

That's simply a design choice of the language. C++ programs are separate units linked together. In what order should the statements be executed when they come from separate source files? How about their execution in relation to initialisation of static objects? The current state of static initialisation is complicated enough; I think it was a good choice to not allow expression statements in namespace scope.

Comment: `int global_n2 = global_n1 = 42;` in C the initializer is not a constant.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, he did write *"My answer is regarding C++. C may be different"*. `:)`